# Passing the resulting array of forkJoin to more than one component in Angular

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a service that does 4 http requests to a server using a forkjoin like so

```
 getData():Observable<any[]>{
    const response1=this.http.get(URL+'/1')
    const response2=this.http.get(URL+'/2')
    const response3=this.http.get(URL+'/3')
    const response4=this.http.get(URL+'/4')
    console.log("recibido")
    this.data= forkJoin([response1, response2, response3,response4])
    return this.data
}
```

So i want to share this resulting Observable array to 2 to components that have to use the result of the forkJoin in a different way.
Obviously calling the function twice is not working since Angular doesnt let me explicitly make two HTTP requests at the same time

I´ve previously used a @Output Decorator to send data ,

```
 data: dataChart
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<dataChart> = new EventEmitter()
  toggleData(poData: dataChart) {
    console.log('do toggle')
    this.data = poData;
    //this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.change.emit(this.data);
    console.log(this.data)
  }
```

I called toggleData() on a component to set the variable this.data and then i called

```
this.service.change.subscribe(data=>{ 
 //Handle the data
})
```

In 4 components to be able to manipulate the data coming from the first component.

Note that all components are siblings

Is it possible to do this with a forkJoin?
Is there another way to get the data from the http server and use its results in various components?

Comment: you can create another subject and call next method.so you can use this subject in 2 different components

Comment: so i have to define the data used in the getData function as a Subject?

Comment: no. you can call your function one time and store the output in service and share it from several components.or you can create another subject and call next method from Http forkJoin subscribe method.in this way, all your components listening to that subject will be notified. also it's possible to write forkjoin conditionally so if data is already there you can avoid http request  and just return existing data

Comment: How would i store the output of the request on a variable so i can use a Subject

Comment: @VictorDanielSantillnChalico use ``BehaviorSubject`` to do the job as it will store the previous value

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to use a Subject here. But you need to do 2 things:

1: Instead of using a function just use a property like that:

```
public data = forkJoin([this.http.get(URL+'/1'), ...])
```

Btw. `forkJoin` also supports a passing an object for better readability, e.g.

```
public data = forkJoin({someProp: this.http.get(URL+'/1'), ...})
```

2. you need to use a proper multicasting mechanism, depending on your usage.
   If you are simultaneously subscribing to the Observable it's likely `share` otherwise `shareReplay(1)`, so it would look like this:

```
public data = forkJoin([this.http.get(URL+'/1'), ...]).pipe(
   share()
)
```

Multicasting Operators in RxJS are using a Subject under the hood as well, but you don't have to manage the lifecycle of it and additionally this is tightly coupled to your source observable. Subjects tend to be misused and be polluted by calling next all over the place.